# Sorry — your last action could not be completed in Paypal in Nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, payment-gateway, nopcommerce

I have implemented recurring payment for **monthly and yearly subscription product** using **PayPalStandard plugin** in Nopcommerce version 2.80.

So, I had passes paypal subscription button variable on the confirm button which will redirect to Paypal site and there I had logged on with my sandbox account to pay with subscription, but I found this error when click on LogIn button:  **Sorry — your last action could not be completed**

So, I want to go beyond this error.
Anyone can plz help me!!

Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes it happens because of the browser's cookies and cache , Can you try to clear the cookies and cache and try again?

Comment: I had tried but it doesn't work..

Comment: I have resolved this issue.The problem is because of **I am not using sandbox account of Merchant(or Seller)**.That's why transaction is not going make successful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.The problem is because of **I am not using sandbox account of Merchant(or Seller)**.That's why transaction is not going make successful..

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem too.